# How to mutate Genetic Algotithm in dataset features

Tags: data-science, genetic-algorithm

in real world feature selection, how does it Genetic Algorithm work?

How the mutation occure in that case?

Example, if I have a dataset for predict loan approvals

dataset would look like this

Age, Salary, Loan Amount, Property Value, Car Value, Kids, Expenses .... Approve

```
Age Salary Loan Amount Property Value Car Value Kids Expenses.... Approve
47  3500   100,000     250,000        20,000    2    1600         1
34  2200   700,000     130,000        10,000    0    1800         0
38  3200   400,000     150,000        25,000    3    2300         1
42  4500   500,000     200,000        60,000    1    3000         1
55  3000   600,000     100,000        37,000    3    2300         0
```

if we start with parent

Parent 1 : Age, Salary, Car Value, Kids
Parent 2 : Age, Loan Amt, Car Value, Expenses

Offspring : Age, Salary, Car Value, Expenses

to mutate that offspring

Shall the new feature be one of its parents or it can be any feature from the dataset

Is this correct mutattion : Age, Property Value, Car Value, Expenses

To have Property Value instead of Salary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genetic algorithms are a class of evolutionary algorithms that allow reproduction and crossover of members by combining their internal representations (their *genotype*).

There is no general rule for how mutation works in GAs, it is dependent on the specific algorithm. However, let's answer your questions under the assumption of the most common GA specifications/rules:

You crossed over your parents correctly. Usually during crossover the offspring has no trait that hasn't also been present in its parents. Which of the parents traits is copied over to the offspring is often random, therefore your offspring is valid.

During mutation the member is usually looked at in a vacuum - meaning it doesn't matter if the member was created through mutation_x, mutation_y or crossover. The probability that mutation_x, mutation_y or crossover is now applied to the member is the same as for any other member in the population.

Therefore the 'mutation_add_property_value' can be chosen and (assuming you have fixed size genomes, as each member only has 4 features) a random feature such as salary can be replaced. Your mutation to (Age, Property_Value, Car_Value, Expenses) is therefore a valid mutation in the assumed general GA.